# How do I use a variable from a static class in another class?

Tags: java

I's trying to build an encoder like the "Enigma Machine" and I have this code so far where I'm trying to get comboOne() to use the "s" variable from main():

```
import java.io.*;

public class main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("What would you like to encode?");
        String s = br.readLine();

        s.toCharArray();
        System.out.println(s);

        //comboOne comboOne = new comboOne();
    }
}
```

Just to encode one letter I've written this:

```
public class comboOne extends main
{
    main m = new main();
    char message = s.toCharArray();
        if(message == 'a')
    {
        System.out.println('b');
    }
}
```

I am quite new so apologies if I am making an obvious mistake but I think this would be a fun challenge for myself. Please send help and thanks for helping :)

Comment: Please stick to naming conventions. Class names should always be written in **PascalCase**, not **camelCase**. Variable and method names in **camelCase**.

Comment: Variables are visible to the scope in which there are defined, so `s` is only visible to the `main` method of `main`.  Fields on the other hand are  visible based upon their `public/private/protected` declaration.  So consider making `String s` a field **but** why are you even extending from the class `main`?

Comment: I would suggest making `public class Enigma { private String s;}` and research getters/setters

Comment: There is no static class here. Clarify.

Comment: @EJP to clarify: I think OP might need to research what a "static class" is...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add outside your Main.main method

```
public static String s;
```

Then use `Main.s` to access the String in a static way. Since it is static it does not need to be instantiated an can directly be called from the class.

Comment: Funny, that OP understood my hint that Java classes start with a capital letter but Scary Wombat didn't.

Comment: @cricket_007 What did you add?